# Points disappear after some frames.How do I keep them till my animation ends

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, gganimate

I have this data

```
Data <- structure(list(
  Date = c(
    "2020-03-12", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-10",
    "2020-03-10", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-07",
    "2020-03-07", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-06", "2020-03-05",
    "2020-03-04", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-02",
    "2020-03-02", "2020-03-02", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-02", "2020-01-30"
  ), CASES = c(
    2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 6L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
  ), STATE = c(
    "Mumbai       ",
    "Jaipur        ", "Kerala       ", "Karnataka        ", "Jammu       ",
    "Kerala        ", "Kerala        ", "Tamil Nadu       ", "Ladakh       ",
    "Hoshiarpur        ", "Jammu       ", "Delhi      ", "Ghaziabaad UP       ",
    "Gurgaon       ", "Agra       ", "Delhi      ", "Jaipur        ",
    "Jaipur        ", "Hyderabad       ", "Delhi       ", "Kerala        ",
    "Kerala        ", "Kerala        "
  ), CASES_CF = c(
    2L, 3L, 15L,
    3L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 15L, 2L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L
  ), CF = c(
    60L, 58L, 57L, 51L, 48L, 43L, 42L,
    38L, 36L, 34L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 22L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L,
    3L, 2L, 1L
  ), State_wise = c(
    2L, 3L, 35L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 11L, 1L,
    2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L
  ),
  Date2 = c(
    "2020-03-12", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-10",
    "2020-03-09", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-07",
    "2020-03-07", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-06", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-04",
    "2020-03-04", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-02",
    "2020-03-02", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-02", "2020-01-30"
  ),
  Short = c(
    "M", "J", "Ker", "Krn", "Jam", "Ker", "Ker", "TN",
    "lad", "Hosh", "Jmu", "Del", "Gazz", "Gur", "Agr", "Del",
    "Jai", "Jai", "hyd", "Del", "Ker", "Ker", "Ker"
  ), Date3 = c(
    "2020-03-12",
    "2020-03-02", "2020-01-30", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-07", "2020-01-30",
    "2020-01-30", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-07",
    "2020-03-02", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-02",
    "2020-03-02", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-02", "2020-01-30",
    "2020-01-30", "2020-01-30"
  )
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -23L
))
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

class(Data$Date)
Data$Date3 <- as.Date(Data$Date3)
Data$Date3 
B <- ggplot(data = Data,aes(CASES_CF,Data$Date3,colour=Data$STATE,group=Data$STATE))+geom_point()+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1), angle=90))+xlab("Total number of cases confrimed")+ylab("Date")
Text <- B+geom_text(aes(label=Data$STATE),hjust=0, vjust=0)+scale_y_date(breaks = "3 day")
annim <- Text+transition_states(Data$Date2)
annim
```

[This is the result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTzfN.jpg)

[image]

I am having problem getting smooth animation and my `geom_point`s disappear after some frames. With the help of `shadow_mark` I have maintained the path but I want single point to reach the destination without getting disappear.

[Inspired by](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/feupf0/oc_timelapse_of_coronavirus_cases_by_country/)